# No front panel lights or headphone sound

Tags: digital-audio

Out of necessity, I replaced my motherboard with Gigabyte B360M DS3H. While I was able to get everything else to function correctly, I no longer have front panel light or audio to the headphone jack.

I have checked my audio software and it appears to be functioning although I can't hear anything, i.e. no errors and current driver.

Am running windows 10 on this desktop.

Am sure that I just missed plugging something in, but am unsure where to look. Any video or educated advise would be of tremendous help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure someone will be along with a better answer before too long, but in the meantime, have you tried having a look inside the machine (by taking the cover/sides off as required) to check if it is just a cable left unplugged as you suspect?

My dad is very good at fixing things, and it seems to be partly due to his attitude of "it may not fix it, but it won't hurt to have a look inside". As long as you unplug the mains power supply before you open the computer, you are unlikely to cause any damage, and there is a good chance it will be obvious what needs to go where. You've probably figured this out already but you probably want to start by looking on the inside of where the front panel is.

If you are reluctant to try this and prefer a more detailed answer, I'd suggest you edit your question to include the make/model of your machine (more specifically the tower/case). You could also upload some photos, it's really easy, you can google the instructions for this.

Comment: Thanks - I installed the motherboard, so have been in the box. Problem is that I am unsure which wire to plug in where on the board. Everything else works correctly. Appreciate your answer.

Comment: Ok, so it's a bit like ending up with screws in your hand after you put something back together. Have you tried searching for a connection diagram for the box and the motherboard? Both manufacturers should provide one really, even if it's not published on the web and you have to request one from support.